# How to mock a nested function of a smart contract?

Tags: testing, mocking, solidity, smartcontracts, forge

In a foundry test I can mock the result `getReserves()` by using:

```
vm.mockCall(
        poolAddress,
        abi.encodeWithSelector(IUniswapV2Pair.getReserves.selector),
        abi.encode(3000000000000000000, 9000000000000000000000)
);
```

and get the right amounts when the `getReserves()` function is called.
But then if I want to test the `swap` function:

```
IUniswapV2Pair(poolAddress).swap(
        0, 
        amountOut,
        address(this),
        new bytes(0)
);
```

And there is a nested call to `getReserves()` in this `swap` call but it is not using the mocked function, rather it makes a call and get the actual on chain reserves.

How can I mock the **nested call **to the `getReserves()` function?

I tried to add all functions of the `Pair` contract to a mock contract but that did not work.